# Amazon AWS RDS - MySQL CommunicationsException

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've an issue with Amazon AWS/RDS MySQL connection. In some cases I get an error 500 on the (mobile)client. If I have a look at the Amazon Cloud-Watch logs I see the following error:

> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 83,292,955 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 83,292,958 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your app
>   play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 83,292,955 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 83,292,958 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.]

It seems to be a connection issue with the MySQL Database. Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

The current setting for `wait_timeout` is the default one. See config above

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, die not found a solution.

Comment: The last sentence of the error message has a suggestion for what to do. Did you try any of that?

Comment: I tried but without success.